# derivative of $y=\sqrt{10^{5-x}}=u^{1/2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y=\sqrt{10^{5-x}}=u^{1/2}$

$y\;'=\dfrac{1}{2}u^{-1/2}\times u\;'=\dfrac{1}{2}(10^{5-x})^{-1/2}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{10^{5-x}}}\times 10^{5-x}\ln10(-1)$

$=\dfrac{10^{5-x}\ln10(-1)}{2\sqrt{10^{5-x}}}$

However the correct answer is: $-\dfrac{10^{.5(5-x)}}{2}\ln(10)$
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\displaystyle\frac{10^{5-x}\ln(10)(-1)}{2\sqrt{10^{5-x}}} = -\frac{\sqrt{10^{5-x}}\ln(10)}{2} = -\frac{10^{.5(5-x)}}{2}\ln10$$

You didn't had any problems, you just didn't complete the simplification of the fraction.

Answer (score 1):

Write $y=10^{(5-x)/2}$ and recall $(b^{x})'=b^{x}\ln b$

Then the chain rule implies (with $u=(5-x)/2$ and $u'=-1/2$) that

$$y'=\frac{-\ln 10}{2}10^{(5-x)/2}.$$